# One-to-one or zero Entity Framework Fluent API

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I'm using Fluent API to create a one-to-one or zero relationship and in first case 
Manager - ContactDetails it works but in second case Representative - ContactDetails it doesn't. But the configuration is the same.

As far as I understand in a one-to-one/zero relations one of two classes should define a key as primary and foreignKey so that it is known which class is dependent. And for example Id in ContactDetails can't be a foreignKey for both Representative and Manager table at the same time? That's why a Representative_Id is automatically created? But why is this relationship is considered as one to many?

[image]

**Manager Class:**

```
  [Table("Manager")]
public class Manager
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactDetail ContactDetail { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

**Representative Class:**

```
[Table("Representative")]
public class Representative
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(99)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Client Client{ get; set; }
   public virtual ContactDetail ContactDetail {get; set; }
}
```

**ContactDetail Class:**

```
    public class ContactDetail
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Manager Manager { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
   public virtual Representative Representative { get; set; }
}
```

**Override method in Context:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

           modelBuilder.Entity<Manager>()
               .HasOptional(m => m.ContactDetail)
               .WithRequired(ad => ad.Manager);

          modelBuilder.Entity<Representative>()
               .HasOptional(c => c.ContactDetail)
               .WithRequired(ad => ad.Representative);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: FYI: one-to-one and many-to-many relationships are illogical and cannot be represented in databases. Only one-to-many relationships are possible

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I need a Manager to have only one ContactDetail or zero and also a Representative will have only one ContactDetail or zero. If I add foreignKeys to ContactDetail table and in the end it will be a one-to-many relationship - how can I achieve that only one record will be added (one Manager - one ContactDetail record) ?  `modelBuilder.Entity<Representative>()
                .HasOptional(r => r.ContactDetail)
                .WithOptionalPrincipal(c => c.Representative)
                .Map(m => m.MapKey("RepresentativeId"));`